# Using one navigation drawer that shows different options depending on the activity that is currently showing

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer in a BaseActivity, that shows different options depending on the activity that is currently showing. For that, I developed a BaseActivity, that implements the navigation drawer, and decides what to show, depending on the activity that is currently showing. The purpose of this, is to make all other activities that need to use the navigation drawer, expand the BaseActivity.

The following code, shows no errors, but the navigation drawer shows itself completely empty, and does not show when I click the 'home' button, neither the 'menu' button, a functionality that I implemented with the 'onKeyDown' method. It just shows, when I use the following gesture: move the finger from the left to the right in the left side of the screen.

When I do the same in each class I need, instead of using a BaseActivity, everything works perfeclty fine.

I have been trying this for days now and I still do not understand why, the content of the navigation drawer is still not showing. I would appreciate some help please. Thanks in advance.

Here, the core classes of the problem:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout = null;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = null;
    public Activity currentActivity = null;
    public ArrayList<Item> navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public ItemListAdapter adapter = null;
    public ListView drawerList = null;
    int id = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int resLayoutID)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(resLayoutID);
        currentActivity = this;

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(currentActivity,
                                                 drawerLayout,
                                                 R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                                 R.string.open_menu,
                                 R.string.close_menu)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                Log.e("", "Close drawer");
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(currentActivity);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                Log.e("", "Open drawer");
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(currentActivity);
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Populate navigation drawer depending on the activity
        // that is currently showing.
        if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Z"))
            setUpNavigationForZActivity();
    }

    private void setUpNavigationForZActivity()
    {
        Log.e("", "In setUpNavigationForZActivity");

        // Prepare list items.
        id = R.string.title_activity_A;
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(getString(id), Utils.activityIcon().get(id)));
        id = R.string.title_activity_B;
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(getString(id), Utils.activityIcon().get(id)));

        // Populate view.
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_menu);
        adapter = new ItemListAdapter(currentActivity, navDrawerItems;
        drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id)
            {
                Intent intent = null; 
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(currentActivity, A.class);
                        startActivity(intent)
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(currentActivity, B.class);
                        startActivity(intent)
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        Log.e("", "onKeyDown");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        {
            if(!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            else
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
}
```

**Z.java**

```
public class Z extends BaseActivity
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.Z);
        setContentView(R.layout.Z);

        //Other things to do...
    }
}
```

**Z.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Main content view -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        // Other layout and views configurations...
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/gray_7_5"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, so after very long research, I discovered, that the problem was that I was setting the layour twice, so the only thing I needed to do was to remove the following line from the Z.java: setContentView(R.layout.Z);. I do not need to set the content here, because I am doing it in the BaseActivity. Hope that this solution helps some people and save some hours of work :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly know why you would want to implement it that way but if you still want to do it this way i would suggest making your navdrawer use a listview with an adapter to draw items from an array and then have your base activity have a getData() call that you can override in your derived activities that will supply the data that the Adapter so that the listview will then draw the appropriate items in the navdrawer. You will then have to implement the onItemClick event for each listview per activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply LeMon.xaH and also for your approach, but why or what is wrong in my approach? That is what I do not understand still.